# How to disable automatic addition of filters into filter panel with each new data table?

Tags: spotfire

Do you know how to disable automatic addition of filters into filter panel with each new data table? This behavior is very annoying especially if you have several pages of visulizations and you add a new data table. Spotfire automatically adds all variables from a new data table into filtering panel of all pages and I have to go into each page and manually hide the last added table from filter panel.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to tools => Options => choose Document. Check the options on the bottom. It says "Filters for in-memory data tables". Set to "manage manually".

Comment: Changing this setting is working, thanks, but only if data is added through File => Add Data Table. If you drop table into visualization, filters still get automatically added into panel.